# sorting based on all columns element and select with a threshold

Tags: r

I have a data looks like this

```
df<- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(6L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L
), .Label = c("A0A0G2JDV6", "P01901", "P13745", "Q03141", "Q3TMK4", 
"Q3UCW4", "Q8CBE6", "Q8VCQ8"), class = "factor"), V2 = c(1.234548336, 
0.982968881, 1.521367521, 1.00623053, 0.868106341, 1.035714286, 
0, 2.436170213), V3 = c(1.185419968, 1.131202691, 1.558404558, 
0.775700935, 0.74580573, 0.897230321, 0, 2.686170213), V4 = c(1.0681458, 
1.08999159, 1.715099715, 0.943925234, 0.774627893, 0.927842566, 
0, 2.287234043), V5 = c(1.535657686, 1.25862069, 2.068376068, 
1.012461059, 0.828314549, 1.04664723, 0, 2.579787234), V6 = c(1.605388273, 
1.280277544, 1.792022792, 0.875389408, 0.828357567, 1.183673469, 
0, 2.558510638)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

I import the data as

```
df <- read.delim(" path to the data/df.txt", encoding="ASCII", header=FALSE)
```

what I want to do is to sort them based on all columns 
for example the one which has all 4 values higher than the rest rows come the first this repeated to the end

So the output will look like below called df2

```
A0A0G2  2.436170213 2.686170213 2.287234043 2.579787234 2.558510638
P13745  1.521367521 1.558404558 1.715099715 2.068376068 1.792022792
Q3UCW4  1.234548336 1.185419968 1.0681458   1.535657686 1.605388273
P01901  0.982968881 1.131202691 1.08999159  1.25862069  1.280277544
Q03141  1.035714286 0.897230321 0.927842566 1.04664723  1.183673469
Q8CBE6  1.00623053  0.775700935 0.943925234 1.012461059 0.875389408
Q3TMK4  0.868106341 0.74580573  0.774627893 0.828314549 0.828357567
Q8VCQ8  0              0           0            0         0
```

And from this df2, I want to select those that all values are higher than a value (for example 1.1) so the df3 will be

```
A0A0G2  2.436170213 2.686170213 2.287234043 2.579787234 2.558510638
P13745  1.521367521 1.558404558 1.715099715 2.068376068 1.792022792
```

Comment: What if some values in a row are higher than another and some values are lower than the other, how would you arrange them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the desired output, you can use a combination of `order` and `rowSums`. Using:

```
df2 <- df[order(rowSums(df[,-1]), decreasing = TRUE),]
```

gives:

```
> df2
          V1        V2        V3        V4        V5        V6
8 A0A0G2JDV6 2.4361702 2.6861702 2.2872340 2.5797872 2.5585106
3     P13745 1.5213675 1.5584046 1.7150997 2.0683761 1.7920228
1     Q3UCW4 1.2345483 1.1854200 1.0681458 1.5356577 1.6053883
2     P01901 0.9829689 1.1312027 1.0899916 1.2586207 1.2802775
6     Q03141 1.0357143 0.8972303 0.9278426 1.0466472 1.1836735
4     Q8CBE6 1.0062305 0.7757009 0.9439252 1.0124611 0.8753894
5     Q3TMK4 0.8681063 0.7458057 0.7746279 0.8283145 0.8283576
7     Q8VCQ8 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

To get only the rows in which all the values are higher than `1.1`, you can use:

```
df2[rowSums(df2[,-1] > 1.1) == 5, ]
```

which gives:

```
          V1       V2       V3       V4       V5       V6
8 A0A0G2JDV6 2.436170 2.686170 2.287234 2.579787 2.558511
3     P13745 1.521368 1.558405 1.715100 2.068376 1.792023
```

Comment: thanks I liked and I accepted it; however, it is possible to also select only those which the values increase over columns ? for example higher than 1.1

Comment: @nik If I understand you correctly you use a logical vector like `(df2$V2 < df2$V3) & (df2$V3 < df2$V4) & (df2$V4 < df2$V5) & (df2$V5 < df2$V6)` tot subset your dataframe.

Comment: Yes it is as you say

Answer (score 0):

**Edit : The sorting is done wrong in this answer.** Please refer to Procrastinatus Maximus's answer where it is correct. Thanks for pointing it out Procrastinatus Maximus :)

Sort by all the five columns in descending order

```
df2 <- df[order(df$V2, df$V3, df$V4, df$V5, df$V6, decreasing = TRUE), ]
```

Keep only the rows where all values are greater than 1.1

```
df3 <- df2[apply(X = df2[paste0("V", 2:6)], MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) all(x > 1.1)), ]
```

Let me know if it helps

Comment: for `df3` you can just do `df2[apply(df2[,-1], 1, function(x)all(x>1.1)),]`

Comment: @Sotos : Yes. I like it. Makes the code shorter. Thanks :) Edited the answer

Comment: The ordering doesn't give the desired output as far as I can see.

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus : All the values of a row greater than other rows. That means that the sum will be greater than the other rows too. You are correct. Thanks :) Sorry about the mistake. Edited the answer. And frankly, your answer is better readable with rowSums. Cheers!

Comment: Nice that you copied my ordering solution. But when you do something like that, it is best to give credit to the one you copied from ;-)

Comment: @DavidArenburg : Yeah. Doesnt feel right :( Reverted the changes

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus : Sorry about the copy. Did not feel right to me. Reverted it. And added a mention saying that the sorting is done wrong in this answer. Thanks for being cool about it :)

Comment: np, this site is about educating people; consequently I try to keep my comments aligned with that goal ;-)